# 40 If-Statements in a Loop, How to Avoid?

Tags: java, jinput

I am working with the library JInput to detect controller input in a java game. However, in order to get the direction the axis is moving, I use this:

```
gamePadContr.getComponent(Identifier.Axis.X).getPollData();
```

This gives me a decimal between -1 and 1, which tell the direction.  I want the player to be able to move in more than just up, down, left, and right, so there are 40 if statements in my gameloop that check if the number is a certain set of numbers, and increasing the x and y coordinates accordingly.  Here is an example:

```
if(x > .1 && x < .2 && y == 1){
   // do stuff
} else
if(x > .2 && x < .3 && y == 1{
  // do stuff
}
```

I have to check each one to make sure that most directions are accounted for.

My point is, 40 if statements is lagging. **Is there anything I can do to optimize this?**

A few edits to answer questions:

1. Didn't think it was relevant, but the reason increments of .1 have 40 different if statements is because I am checking the X and Y axis of the joystick. The possible combinations are (1, -1)  (1, 1)  (-1, 1)  (-1, -1), giving me negatives and positives in 40 different combinations at increments of .1. (I don't know if that made sense.
2. //do stuff is just increasing the x and y coordinates of the player by certain amounts.

Comment: Vectors, sin, cos, trigonometry

Comment: How does a decimal between -1 and 1 give you 40 cases when you are dividing the range up in increments of 0.1? Also, your posted code only reacts to `x < .2` and `x > .2`; what happens at exactly x == .2, etc?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you do in `// do stuff`? How do you move the player? Do you see any patterns? How can you use these patterns to eliminate the `if` statements?

Comment: My main question here is what are some alternatives that can optimize this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach might be to discover a rule whereby you can directly compute the player's coordinate change directly from the joystick coordinates. For that, we would need details of what `// do stuff` is for each branch.

Another possibility, which is good if you don't have a simple relationship, is to convert your tests to a look-up by transforming the `x` and `y` values to array indexes

```
int xIndex = (int) (10 * x + 10); // an int between 0 and 20
int yIndex = (int) (10 * y + 10); // ditto
```

Then you can look up the player's coordinate changes in a 2-D array that you compute once ahead of time. More generally, you could have an array of `Runnable` objects, look up the appropriate `Runnable` based on the indexes, and `run()` it.

P.S. If each joystick coordinate can fall into any of 20 different ranges, then you have 400 cases, not 40. That is, unless you are always ignoring one or the other of the axes.

Comment: Nice solution for the array lookup. +1

Comment: Wuoldn't that be 21 different ranges and 441 cases?

Comment: @Turo - Yeah, probably. it depends on how you deal with endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is nest your conditions.  Instead of

```
if (x > .1 && x < .2 && y == 1){doStuff();}
else if (x > .2 && x < .3 && y == 1){doStuff();}
else if (x > .1 && x < .2 && y == 2){doStuff();}
else if (x > .2 && x < .3 && y == 2){doStuff();}
```

you may want to consider:

```
if (y == 1){
    if (x > .1 && x < .2){doStuff();}
    else if (x > .2 && x < .3){doStuff();}
}
else if (y == 2)
{
    if (x > .1 && x < .2){doStuff();}
    else if (x > .2 && x < .3){doStuff();}
}
```

Now your code can skip all the if checks that it knows aren't true.  Instead of having to check up to 20*20 = 400 if statements, the program only has to check up to 20+20=40 if statements in any given loop.  You will still HAVE a ton of if statements - in fact, you'll have slightly more than you had before - but 90% of them will be skipped, and they'll each be shorter, so the program will run faster.

You can also reduce the number of checks in each if statement with clever ordering.  If you already checked `x < .5` and it was false, then you already know that `x < .4` is false.  For example:

```
if (y == 1){
    if (x > .9 ){doStuff();}
    else if (x > .8){doStuff();} // no need to check if it's less than .9 since the previous line covered that case
}
```

Comment: There could also be some simplifications if x and y are independent of each other - you wouldn't even have to nest the conditionals; they could just be separate.  Although that array lookup thing in the other answer is probably better.